Tensor product not left exact, but does it preserve inclusions of submodules?
The question is in the title: i know that tensor products generally don't preserve injectivity (of module maps, in the case of my question), but what about inclusions of submodules? This is a special case, I think.
My thoughts: Let $A$ and $B$ be rings (commutative with $1$), let $A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism, let $M$ be an $A$-module and $M'\subseteq M$ an $A$-submodule.
Consider the map $\iota\colon M'\to M, m'\mapsto m'$ (i.e. the inclusion). This is obviously injective.
Consider the base changed map $\iota\otimes id_B\colon M'\otimes_A B\to M\otimes_A B, m'\otimes b\to \iota(m')\otimes b$ (defined as usual). This should be injective, no?
Choose some $m'\otimes b$ in the kernel of $\iota\otimes id_B$, then $\iota(m')\otimes b = 0$. But as $\iota(m') = m'$, we have that $m'\otimes b = 0$ obtaining a trivial kernel.
Am I not seeing something?
This would not be a contradiction to the fact that tensor products are not left exact as for injective maps $N\to M$, $N$ is only isomorphic to a submodule of $M$ such that the construction above obviously fails.

If $M$ and $N$ are $A$-modules, $m\in M$ and $n\in N$, then the notation $m\otimes n$ denotes the image of $(m,n)$ under the canonical bilinear map $\phi:M\times N\to M\otimes_A N$. So the notation $m\otimes n$ hides the dependence on the modules $M$ and $N$, and it can be ambiguous if, say, we start considering submodules $M'$ and $N'$ of $M$ and $N$ respectively (perhaps $m\otimes n$ denotes the image of $(m,n)$ under the map $M\times N\to M\otimes_A N$). This might be what caused your confusion.

Yes, it actually would be a contradiction to the fact the tensor products are not left exact. Because if $N\to M$ is injective, it factors as $N\to N'\to M$ where $N\to N'$ is an isomorphism and $N'\to M$ is an inclusion map ($N'$ is just the image of $N\to M$ of course).
So if $N'\otimes B\to M\otimes B$ is injective as you claim, then so is $N\otimes B\to M\otimes B$, since $N\otimes B\to N'\otimes B$ is an isomorphism (any functor preserves isomorphisms).
So what is the flaw with your proof? The problem is that you already implicitly assume that $M'\otimes B$ is a submodule of $M\otimes B$ when you write your proof. (Also, it is not enough to check elements of the form $m'\otimes b$, but that is not the real issue.)
What you proved is that if $m'\otimes b$ is in the kernel of $\iota\otimes Id_B$, then the element of $M\otimes B$ written as $m'\otimes b$ is $0$. But that does not prove that the element of $M'\otimes B$ written as $m'\otimes b$ is $0$, precisely because $M'\otimes B$ is not a submodule of $M\otimes B$. It is a different module altogether, and the best you can say is that it has some canonical map $\iota\otimes id_B: M'\otimes B\to M\otimes B$ which relates the two, but (as we now know) is not injective in general.

Standard counterexample: Consider ring $A = \mathbb{Z}$ so that $A$-modules are just abelian groups. Let $M = M' = \mathbb{Z}$ be the rank $1$ free modules with inclusion $\iota: \mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ given by $\iota(m) = 2m$. Finally, let $B = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.
Claim: $\iota \otimes \operatorname{id}_B: M' \otimes B \to M \otimes B$ is the zero map, hence not injective.
Why? Any element of the source is a sum of pure tensor $m' \otimes b$, but
$$
(\iota \otimes \operatorname{id}_B)(m' \otimes b) = \iota(m') \otimes \operatorname{id}_B(b) = 2m' \otimes b = m' \otimes 2b = m' \otimes 0 = 0. 
$$
This of course works for lots of generalizations where the inclusion matches up with the torsion of $B$, e.g., $\mathbb{Z} \overset{k}{\hookrightarrow} \mathbb{Z}$ with $A = \mathbb{Z}$ and $B = \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$.
